# Is it possible to pass a radiobuttonList to a method in a custom class as a parameter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a few different pages with a radiobutton list that I populate using a collection of answers in the page load event of each page. I was wondering rather than repeating the same code on 4 different pages, is it possible to pass in the radio button list as a parameter to my own class that I made and populate it in there? I can't seem to see A ListItem parameter to pass in.

My code is

```
    foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    RadioButtonList.Items.Add(item);
                }
```

Instead of having to repeat that, I'm trying to pass the list and the collection to my Person Class, and create a method in there that does the same.Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, can you not have something like a static function that has the `RadioButtonList` and collection as parameters?

```
public static void PopulateMyRadios(RadioButtonList rdoButtons, MyCollection collection)
{
  foreach (var item in collection)
  {
    rdoButtons.Items.Add(item);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Where do I have that method though so all the pages of my website can access it though? If I place it in the first page, only the first page can call on that method.

Comment: Create a public static class in your app called "Library" or whatever, and then all your code behinds will be able to use the methods (like the one above) in it.

Comment: As @Graham says, either create a `public static class`, or put it in your first class (e.g. `MyPage1`) and then just call `MyPage1.PopulateMyRadios(myRadios, myCol);` in your other pages.  By making it `public static` means you don't need to create a new instance of the class, and it will be available to all other classes

Comment: I've tried this but RadioButtonList is not recognised as a parameter type in a method that I create myself, it's only recognised when I'm in the classes of my pages

Comment: I've only seen your comment now @freefaller, I got it! Thanks

Comment: Good, glad to hear it @John :-)  Please remember to upvote those answers you find useful, and mark as answered the one answer that suited you best.  That way the community knows your problem is solved, and helps others who find your question at a later date

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. We can create a method of parameter string array which are hold the text of radio button required. Then create html radio button list by using string array and input this radio button list to any of div of corresponding page as inner HTML.